# Verify if a User is new or already exists Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am working on a application and i use firebase for user login authentication and everything works perfect. Recently i thought of a new idea for the app and i would like to check if a user exists or if its the first time. if its the first time the user goes to a new activity and if the user exists it goes to the home activity. i tried documentations and i didn't really understand. Can someone help me with code sample or better explanation.

this is the login code

```
private void user_login(String email, String password) {

    if (email.isEmpty()){
      emailtx.setError("email is empty");
      emailtx.requestFocus();
    }
    if (password.isEmpty()){
        passwordtx.setError("password is empty");
        passwordtx.requestFocus();
    }
    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        emailtx.setError("Please enter a valid email");
        emailtx.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (password.length()< 6){
        passwordtx.setError("password is short");
        passwordtx.requestFocus();
    }



    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                        String user_id = current_user.getUid();

                        String device_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);




                        HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                        userMap.put("image", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bookshare-8e018.appspot.com/o/male.png?alt=media&token=60cbb24c-b9f9-4724-b8bf-69a76386fcca");
                        userMap.put("thumb_image", "default");
                        userMap.put("device_token", device_token);
                        userMap.put("home", "earth");
                        userMap.put("work", "earth");
                        userMap.put("others", "earth");

                        mDatabase.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if(task.isSuccessful()){


                                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(login.this, selectestado.class);
                                    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                                    finish();

                                }

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
```

Comment: Do you need to figure out if a user is new or existing based on the user's email?

Comment: Yes, also if the user uses Facebook ou Google sign up

Answer (score 0):

below mDatabase you can check if the user exists

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                        HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                        userMap.put("image", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bookshare-8e018.appspot.com/o/male.png?alt=media&token=60cbb24c-b9f9-4724-b8bf-69a76386fcca");
                        userMap.put("thumb_image", "default");
                        userMap.put("device_token", device_token);
                        userMap.put("home", "earth");
                        userMap.put("work", "earth");
                        userMap.put("others", "earth");

                        mDatabase.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if(task.isSuccessful()){


                                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(login.this, selectestado.class);
                                    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                                    finish();

                                }

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

       }
  }else{ 
     //User does not exists
       }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Comment: please how can i do this ?

Comment: inside your signInWithEmailAndPassword and below mDatabase

Comment: okay, but what code am i going to use ?

Comment: when you point to a reference in your database, lets say your userID here with your mDatabase , you can check if that data exists in your database in order to do something, in this case we use if(dataSnapshot.exists()) to check if the user exists in your database, and if that exists we do the task you want to execute.

Comment: in the else statment of the if condition , the user is not present in the database, that means that the user is new

Comment: okay so instead of using the else for a Authentication fail i can use it for new users?

Comment: wait i think i have an idea